# Is Ubuntu Core 22.04.1 Real Time not avaliable for personal use?

Tags: ubuntu-core, realtime

I've recently deployed the Ubuntu Core 22 Real time OS into a raspberry pi 4 in order to deploy an application using the real time [feature they announced recently](https://ubuntu.com/blog/real-time-ubuntu-is-now-generally-available). When I run $uname -a I can not see the PREEMPT_RT Kernell installed ( I have regular  PREEMPT). I was told Ubuntu core 22 already had the preempt_rt kernell installed. Am I missing something? Can I use an older version of Ubuntu Core in order to have a preempt_rt kernell?

Regards,
Domenec.

Comment: Please clarify your OS, Ubuntu Core 22 is a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, but you mix up and use Ubuntu Core and 22.04 which are from different products. Are you using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server? or Ubuntu Core 22?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1024-raspi aarch64)
 * Ubuntu Core:     https://www.ubuntu.com/core
 * Community:       https://forum.snapcraft.io
 * Snaps:           https://snapcraft.io

This Ubuntu Core 22 machine is a tiny, transactional edition of Ubuntu,
designed for appliances, firmware and fixed-function VMs.

Sorry for the confusion , I'm using Ubuntu Core

Comment: I'm a user of the *year.month* products, but from your additional detail you're using Ubuntu Core 22, which is a *specialist flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server.  Your system is Ubuntu Core & release 22, your 22 system is a *flavor* built from 22.04 is all I see the message as telling you.

Comment: So.. I'm using the wrong version?

Comment: I'm just expressing my belief that you're references to 22.04 are incorrect, your system is Ubuntu Core 22.  Ubuntu Core 22 is a *specialist flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS but you're using Ubuntu Core 22  (only Ubuntu Core 22 OR Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question. As outlined in [the announcement you shared](https://ubuntu.com/blog/real-time-ubuntu-is-now-generally-available), Ubuntu Core with the real-time kernel is available for enterprise customers with an [App Store](https://ubuntu.com/internet-of-things/appstore). If you already have a commercial deployment, you can reach out to your sales/field engineering representative at Canonical, and they'll make sure your Ubuntu Core devices are running the real-time kernel.

Alternatively, the real-time Ubuntu kernel is available for free for personal use via [Ubuntu Pro](https://ubuntu.com/pro). All you need to do is [set up a personal subscription](https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard) and then launch the kernel as per:

```
pro attach <free token> 

pro enable realtime-kernel
```

I hope this helps.

Best,
Edoardo

Comment: Hey Edoardo, thank you for your answer.
I suppose the free personal use via Ubuntu Pro is for not for Ubuntu Core but for other versions of Ubuntu. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.